# animating multiple body trajectories in octave

Tags: animation, octave

I know the `hold on;` command in octave allows me to plot multiple trajectories in the same figure. However, i recently came across the function 'comet'. It animates the state of a system over the time range defined by the user. I have only successfully used it for a simple code which shows the trajectory of a small body around a fixed massive body. How can I use 'comet' to animate the trajectories of 2 bodies over the same time range?

PS: If you need an example of how 'comet' works, here is the simple code i mentioned above:

```
function xdot = f(x,t)
  G = 1.37;
  M = 10^5;
  [T,r] = cart2pol(x(1),x(2));
  xdot(3) = -((G*M)/((x(1)^2) + (x(2)^2)))*cos(T);
  xdot(4) = -((G*M)/((x(1)^2) + (x(2)^2)))*sin(T);
  xdot(1) = x(3);
  xdot(2) = x(4);
endfunction

X = lsode ("f", [1000,0,5,10],(t = linspace(0,1000,2000)'));
comet(X(:,1),X(:,2),0.01);
```

This basically plots the trajectory over time. You can copy paste to octave and see the animation.

Can anyone tell me how I can doe the same for a 2 body or multiple body system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use comet in that way. You'll have to do the 'animation' manually, but it's not hard. Plus, you get better customisability. Here's one approach.

```
X1 = lsode ("f", [1000, 0, 5, 10], (t = linspace(0,1000,2000)'));
X2 = lsode ("f", [500,  0, 4, 5 ], (t = linspace(0,1000,2000)'));
x_low  = min ([X1(:, 1); X2(:, 1)]);    x_high = max ([X1(:, 1); X2(:, 1)]);
y_low  = min ([X1(:, 2); X2(:, 2)]);    y_high = max ([X1(:, 2); X2(:, 2)]);

for n = 1 : size (X1, 1)
  plot (X1(1:n, 1), X1(1:n, 2), ':', 'color', [0, 0.5, 1], 'linewidth', 2);
  hold on; 
  plot (X1(n, 1), X1(n, 2), 'o', 'markerfacecolor', 'g', 'markeredgecolor', 'k', 'markersize', 10);
  plot (X2(1:n, 1), X2(1:n, 2), ':', 'color', [1, 0.5, 0], 'linewidth', 2);
  plot (X2(n, 1), X2(n, 2), 'o', 'markerfacecolor', 'm', 'markeredgecolor', 'k', 'markersize', 10);
  hold off;   
  axis ([x_low, x_high, y_low, y_high]); % needed, otherwise first few plots will
                                         % use automatic axis limits
  drawnow; pause(0.01);
end
```

This is the most straightforward way, but its speed might not be as fast as 0.01, if the refresh rate is slower than the time it takes to produce the plot; you can make it even faster if you only plot once and change the data of each plot object at each step instead.

Also, this 'animation' is simply for visualising *inside* an octave session. If you want to produce a video file from this instead, you'll have to produce images and convert to a movie / gif format etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks great to me.